# List all enabled services for both Redhat and Debian

Tags: debian, redhat-enterprise-linux

Is there a trick to display a list of enabled services in both Redhat and Debian distro ?
I need a generic command which can be used for both distribution and with the same output result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Soon (how soon???) both will transition to *systemd*, in which case the command will be:

```
  sudo systemctl -a
```

Until then, it is

```
  sudo service --status-all 
  sudo initctl list
```

for for sysvinit and upstart jobs, respectively.